# D-Link DWL-G122 NetWork

Tags: hard-link

I'm starting downloading ubuntu now, and I have a doubt, my computer needs a USB stick with wireless network to achieve .. And anyone know where I can download the drivers for this model? Or does anyone know how to solve this?

The model is D-Link DWL-G122.

I'm sorry if this question has here, I'm posting before searching.

Thank you :)

And sorry for my bad English, it's because I'm a Brazilian guy :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iirc DWL-G122 uses the rt73 kernel module so should work as far as I can tell. boot the installer best way to find out IMO.

Comment: Strings Thanks, I'm burning the image now, and when everything is ready, I'll try. Thanks again :)